# How to set the size of the dialog like auto, but add an extra 10 pixels?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want the exact same behaviour as what jquery ui's auto, so I have:

```
$("#d").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    auto: true
});
```

Now want I want is the same sizing behaving that the above would give me, but I want to increase the height by 10 pixels.

How can i do this?

Comment: Try to change the `minHeight` property. The default is 150px.

Comment: I think minHeight and maxHeight are broken.

Comment: ehmm in css: `#d{padding-bottom: 10px} ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add 10px of CSS padding to the dialog content (since I'm pretty sure `dialog` uses `innerHeight` to calculate the content height) or just add 10px to the height after the dialog opens. Something like this:

```
var my_dialog = $("#d");

my_dialog.dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    auto: true,
    open: function() {
        my_dialog.css('height', my_dialog.height() + 10);
    }
});
```

*Consider this pseudo-code -- I haven't tested it*

I heartily recommend you try the css solution first though - Don't hack unless necessary

Comment: The thing is, I added a footer that is similiar to the header i.e. if there is a scroll bar, it is fixed.

Comment: also, could I re-use the selector $("#d") so I don't keep referencing it somehow?

Comment: @user1361315: Sure, why not - Updated the answer

Comment: Strange, this worked in firefox but not in IE for some reason. (the open function).